# CAPTCHA for Meteor accounts when registering with email

Tags: meteor

The `accounts-ui` package doesn't have a CAPTCHA mechanism for email registration. Users can register simply by entering an email and a password.

Any plans to incorporate CAPTCHA in the `accounts-ui` package? What would be a good alternative until then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I fully agree with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22039917/1064151), if you really must have captcha within your project, there is a third party package on atmosphere for [visualcaptcha](https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/captcha) integration.

Since everything on Meteor is open source, you can create a copy of the accounts-ui package (just like other people did with accounts-ui-bootstrap and many other similar packages) or create your own [custom login ui](http://blog.benmcmahen.com/post/41741539120/building-a-customized-accounts-ui-for-meteor) to integrate the capthca package.

And while you are at it, you can publish that on Atmosphere so that anyone else looking for a similar thing can use it.

Regarding that being a built-in part of meteor core packages, I highly doubt it since it is really very unnecessary (*opinionated*) for most projects.

Answer (score 3):

Meteor is a JavaScript framework, so any spambot would have to run a headless browser in order to automatically register. Still possible, but somewhat more difficult than for ordinary sites.

There is already a verification mechanism in place: the [`Meteor.user()` object](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_users) has an `emails` key, which is an array of objects with `address` and `verified` fields. The `verified` field will tell you if the user has verified the email address by clicking the signup link that Meteor sent.